# Switching from SimpleStrategy to NetworkTopologyStrategy, getting "ConfigurationException: Unknown data-center name"

Tags: cassandra

We are trying to add new data centre as per the document https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/production/multiDCperWorkloadType.html. When we try to follow
steps 2

In existing data centers, if the SimpleStrategy replication strategy is in use, change it to the NetworkTopologyStrategy replication strategy.

```
ALTER KEYSPACE system_auth WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'Cassandra' : 2, 'dc1': 2};
```

Error

```
ConfigurationException: Unknown data-center name 'dc1' passed to NetworkTopologyStrategy for keyspace 'test': it is either unknown to the configured snitch, or has no active member (known DCs: {Cassandra: 3 nodes})
```

**endpoint_snitch**: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify a non-existent DC when changing the replication settings of a keyspace.

In Cassandra 4.0, it is no longer possible to specify invalid DCs with the `CREATE KEYSPACE` or `ALTER KEYSPACE` commands ([CASSANDRA-12681](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12681)).

In **step 2** of the document you linked ([Initializing multiple DCs per workload type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/production/multiDCperWorkloadType.html)), you needed to specify just the existing DCs when changing the replication settings in preparation for setting up the new DCs.

Once you've managed to re-provisioned the nodes and added the new DCs, you should then be able to specify the new DCs in the replication settings as per **step 9** in the document. Cheers!

Comment: To initialize the new DC of 3 Node getting gossip error. I have updated the question.

Comment: That's unrelated to the original question you posted. 

Comment: I have open separate case for gossip error https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323615/3-node-cluster-gossip-error

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're attempting to configure replication to a DC that Cassandra is not aware of yet

Based on the error, you only have 1 DC called `Cassandra`. The new DC should exist before replication is configured

Running `nodetool status` can give you some insight into the state of your current topology