# Setting up a 3-node cluster, getting exception "Unable to gossip with any peers"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Getting Gossip error when trying to setup 3 node cluster.

1. Node-1:
   Private IP: 10.10.0.1
   Public IP: public_ip_1
2. Node-2:
   Private IP: 10.10.0.2
   Public IP: public_ip_2
3. Node-3:
   Private IP: 10.10.0.3
   Public IP: public_ip_3

Here you go my cassandra.yaml

```
seeds: '10.10.0.1' 
listen_address: 10.10.0.1
broadcast_address: public_ip_1
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_address: public_ip_1
```

Error

```
ERROR [DSE main thread] 2023-02-16 09:38:09,271  CassandraDaemon.java:938 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
```

Node get shut down

Answer (score -1):

For nodes to be able to be able to gossip with each other, there needs to be network connectivity between nodes on TCP port `7000` (`7001` for SSL) in both directions.

If the ports are blocked or if there is no network route then gossip won't work.

If the servers have the wrong time, this will prevent gossip from working since Cassandra uses a server's local time when validating the gossip information from another node. If a server's time is wrong, the gossip information will be rejected as invalid.

Additionally, incorrect permissions on the `commitlog/` directory will block memtable flushes which also stops gossip from working.

For more information, see [Why would a new node be "Unable to gossip with other peers"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323668/). Cheers!

Comment: If we make native_transport_address=0.0.0.0 and native_transport_broadcast_address: public_ip cluster spin up successfully. There is no issues which show there are no constraints of network connectivity or any incorrect permissions on the commit log.

Comment: On the production cluster when adding broadcast_address: public_ip node did not join the cluster with the error 'Unable to gossip with any peers'. with the cluster setting seeds: '10.10.0.1', listen_address: 10.10.0.1 , native_transport_address: 0.0.0.0, native_transport_broadcast_address: public ip. The same setting worked perfectly on a brand-new cluster.